# why is BufferedInputStream reading max 2048 bytes at a time?

Tags: java, android, io, httpurlconnection, bufferedinputstream

I'm trying to read a file from network using `HttpUrlConnection` in an `AsyncTask` in my Android Application.

While i noticed one thing that the file download worked a little slower than it should have, as the network speed i was using was faster.

So i checked and found out that the `BufferedInputStream` object reads only 2048 bytes max at a time. No what buffer size I set. Even internal default buffer size for `BufferedInputStream` is 8192 bytes.

I'm adding my code here for reference.

```
private class DownloadFileTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    BufferedInputStream input = null;
    OutputStream output = null;
    int lengthOfFile;
    int totalBytesDownloaded = 0;
    int count;
    final int bufferSize = 8 * 1024; // 8KB
    try {
      // Create the URL
      URL url = new URL(params[0]);
      // Open connection
      connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      // Get the file length
      lengthOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
      // Input stream to read file - with bufferSize buffer
      input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream(), bufferSize);

      if (isCancelled()) {
        return null;
      }
      // Output stream to write file
      File parentFile = TestUtil.getStorageDir(getApplicationContext(),Constants.EXTRA_DIRECTORY_NAME_TEST_MEDIA);
      File file = new File(parentFile.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "zipFile");

      if (!file.exists()) {
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
      }

      // Create the file o/p stream
      output = new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());

      // Create the buffer o/p stream for performance
      BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(output, bufferSize);

      // Buffer
      byte data[] = new byte[bufferSize];
      while ((count = input.read(data, 0, bufferSize)) != -1 && !isCancelled()) {
        // Increase the total bytes downloaded
        totalBytesDownloaded += count;
        Log.d("DEBUG_LOG","total bytes read : " + count + " buffer size : " + data.length);

        // Write the data to the o/p buffer
        bos.write(data, 0, count);
      }

      // Publish update again since the loop may have skipped the last publish update
      publishProgress(totalBytesDownloaded, lengthOfFile);

      // Flush the o/p stream
      output.flush();
      return file.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (SocketException | SocketTimeoutException e) {
      handler.sendEmptyMessage(Constants.CASE_INTERNET_FAILURE);
      Log.e("DEBUG_LOG", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e("DEBUG_LOG","Error: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
      // closing streams
      if (output != null) {
        try {
          output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          AMLog.e(e);
        }
      }
      if (input != null) {
        try {
          input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          AMLog.e(e);
        }
      }
      if (connection != null) {
        connection.disconnect();
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    int percentage = (values[0] * 100) / values[1] ;
    textDownloadSizeMb.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.label_download_mb), String.valueOf(values[0]), String.valueOf(values[1])));
    textDownloadPercent.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%s%s", percentage, " %"));
    progressBar.setMax(values[1]);
    progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String value) {
  }
}
```

Here is a part of log that shows the data read was never greater than 2048 bytes whereas the buffer size was 8192 bytes.

```
total bytes read : 1748 buffer size : 8192
total bytes read : 2048 buffer size : 8192
total bytes read : 2048 buffer size : 8192
total bytes read : 2048 buffer size : 8192
total bytes read : 1988 buffer size : 8192
```

I've tried multiple buffer sizes greater than 2048 but nothing seems to change the reading rate.

What's the reason behind this? Can i change it to get data in specified buffer size?

Comment: And you're sure the source provides enough successive bytes to read them, because? The JavaDoc of `read` clearly states when it aborts to read more, have you debugged it to check which of the checks fail?

Comment: I tried different sources so wasn't sure if it is limited from the source. I haven't tried debugging inside the read method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because that's all that is ready to be read at any one time, due to the way it is being sent. Nothing you can do about that at this end, except maybe read less often ;-) There's no particular reason to want 8192 bytes at a time: in a correctly written read loop you shouldn't care whether it's one byte or a megabyte, or whatever your buffer size is. The contract of `read()` is merely that it transfers 'at least one byte', unless an exception or end of stream occurs.

Comment: Simple, obvious, and almost certainly right, given both the documentation and a sneeky peek at the source.

Comment: So, This means that it is being blocked from the url source?

Comment: @AkashRaghav What part of 'due to the way it is being sent' didn't you understand?

Comment: @AkashRaghav It's not necessarily being "blocked" -- as in actively made slow -- it could just be the way whatever's serving your data has been written.

Comment: @AkashRaghav It's a perfectly reasonable question. I'm trying to find out whether you understand one word of my answer, or whether you were just trying to get me to reword it.

Comment: I am kind of facing same issue here. I am trying to figure out how to wait until I receive the needed amount of bytes to further process it. I tried using `readFully` but didn't succeded. I posted my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62187087/fastest-and-efficient-way-to-upload-to-s3-using-fileinputstream?noredirect=1&lq=1)